# How to trace a path graphically in a matrix in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a matrix, i.e., a non-ragged list of lists, and given a list of coordinates, for example in form of `{{0,0},{1,1},{2,2},...{5,5}}`, I want to trace a path in that matrix and show the results graphically. A colored band for the path is good enough.

Please help me to write such a function in *Mathematica*. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know if you're aware, but we have a [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica?referrer=hWeRiD9Qz0oIDM_9uBjtlA2) to create a new mathematica specific site in the Stack Exchange network. Please create an account on Area51 and commit to that proposal to help launch it into beta.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's one possibility.

```
pos = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 3},
  {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 5}, {5, 5}};
mat = HankelMatrix[8];
display = Map[Pane[#,{16,20},Alignment->Center]&, mat, {2}];
display = MapAt[Style[#, Background -> Yellow]&, display, pos];
Grid[display, Spacings->{0,0}]
```

[image]

Outlining the entries with a tube, as you describe, is harder.  It can be done, though, if we are willing to step down to graphics primitives.

```
mat = IdentityMatrix[8];
pos = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 3},
  {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 5}, {5, 5}};
pos = Map[{#[[1]], -#[[2]]} &, pos];
outline = {CapForm["Round"], JoinForm["Round"],
  {AbsoluteThickness[30], Line[pos]},
  {AbsoluteThickness[28], White, Line[pos]}};
disks = Table[{Darker[Yellow, 0.07], Disk[p, 0.25]}, 
  {p, pos}];
numbers = MapIndexed[Style[Text[#, {#2[[1]], -#2[[2]]}, 
  {-0.2, 0.2}], FontSize -> 12] &, mat, {2}];
Graphics[{outline, disks, numbers}, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Comment: +1; seems I was 18min late in addition to having an uglier solution! (I completely forgot about `MapAt`)...

Comment: +1. Looks great. I am just wondering if I do `pos = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 
    5}, {5, 5}, {5, 4}, {5, 3}};
Grid[MapAt[
  Style[Pane[#, {16, 20}, Alignment -> Center], 
    Background -> Yellow] &, IdentityMatrix[10], pos], 
 Spacings -> {0, 0}]` I got very untidy graphics in that the spacing is messed up. How to fix it?

Comment: also, is it possible to use a tube-like (or box-like) thing to represent that path? I mean, only draw the outline (like `EdgeForm`) of what your yellow region, or keep the color, but show with a black thick line for the outline of the region.

Comment: @littleEinstein Your graphics are untidy since your `Style` directives don't span the matrix.  We can repair this by adding a `Pane` about each element in the matrix.  Also, see my "tube"-like example.

Answer (score 10):

Another possibility, using `ItemStyle`:

```
m = RandomInteger[10, {10, 10}];
c = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}, {5, 6}, {5, 7}, {4, 8}};
Grid[m, ItemStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Table[i -> {16, Red}, {i, c}]}]
```

Which ends up looking like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 8):

I may have misunderstood the question but this is what I thought you were asking for:

```
coords = Join @@ Array[List, {3, 4}]
{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 
  1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}}

path = RandomSample[coords, Length[coords]]
{{1, 2}, {3, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 1}, {1, 4}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {3, 
  4}, {3, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 1}}

labels = Text[StyleForm[#], #] & /@ coords;


Graphics[Line[path], Epilog -> labels]
```

[image]